# Echo Timestamp field to MDY

Tags: datetime

I am no coder and I'm sure there is an easy answer for this but I cannot seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. In the following, all I want to do is have the "updated" field (which is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the database)timestamp field show just the Month/Day/Year on the page. How do I do this?

```
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query ("SELECT amwx_16_public.member,amwx_16_public.location,amwx_16_public.state,SUM(amwx_events.amount) AS total,amwx_events.updated
    FROM amwx_16_public,amwx_events
    WHERE amwx_16_public.member_id=amwx_events.user_id
    Group By amwx_16_public.member,amwx_events.user_id
    ORDER BY total DESC")
    or die(mysql_error());  
    echo "<table border='5'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Member</th><th>Location</th><th>State</th><th>Total</th><th>Updated</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['member'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['location'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['state'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['total'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['updated'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```